# Deploy static websites to heroku but error : ' couldn't find that app ? '

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am trying to deploy a static website to heroku, and here is what I did.
First, I put my website named `Bai 6 Navbar` into the folder named `Bulma` and then made some commands like this

`git init
git add .
git commit -m "Add useful message"`

Nothing serious. But when I made this command, I met this problem.

```
git push heroku master
```

It said to me that `fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

I tried to fix it by this command : `heroku git:remote -a "Bai 6 Navbar.html"` but it said to me that

```
Error: Couldn't find that app. »   Error ID: not_found
```

I am very confusing because of this problem, could you please give me some ideas with this ? I am a newbie and still studying with this one. Thank you very much.

Comment: Here `heroku` should be mapping to the URL to a remote repository. In a repository created by `git init`, `git remote add heroku <url>` is expected.

Answer (score 0):

To add a `heroku` app as a `Git remote` execute:

```
heroku git:remote -a yourapp.
```

Not that string that you sent as app. `"Bai 6 Navbar.html"`

Here is the source: [Deploying with Git.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)

*EDITED*

The app name is the one you created with `heroku create`.

Follow the docs please.